# Android drawer swapping fragments strategy

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

When using the `android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout`, what is the best strategy to deal with the fragments that fit in the content area? Should I use `fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(fragment).commit()` (then play with show / hide), or use `fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(fragment).commit()`?

If I have a lot of different fragments to display (7), is it better to use the later solution?
Since the fragments are completely destroyed once they are removed from the `FragmentManager`, I guess? But the problem is, if the fragments are dynamically filled with JSON data from the web, then I need to refetch the data every time I display the fragment? Unless I have a cache mechanism, but then, it kinda sounds like the first solution (having the fragments sitting in memory)?

Until now, I only had 3 fragments, so I used the first solution, but going forward, what's the best solution?

Answer (score -1):

> If I have a lot of different fragments to display (7), is it better to use the later solution?

It depends on how memory-intensive your fragments are, it may be just fine to keep them around.

> But the problem is, if the fragments are dynamically filled with JSON
>   data from the web, then I need to refetch the data every time I
>   display the fragment?

You might be able to cache some of the data after the original download. Since I'm not familiar with your business requirements I'm not sure if that's an option for you.

```
what's the best solution?
```

What I usually do is cache the data after the initial download.  If it's a fragment that will be accessed very often I keep it around.  Also, if possible perhaps you could reduce the number of needed of fragments by combining some of the functionality.

Hope that helps.